# UIWebview won't load after segue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, youtube

I want to play a youtube movie after I clicked a row. I am doing it at the following way.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showVideo" sender:indexPath];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
        Video *video = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // ask NSFRC for the NSMO at the  row in question
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showVideo"]) {
             NSLog(@"url is: %@",video.url);
             [segue.destinationViewController setVideoURL:[NSURL URLWithString:video.url]];

        }
}
```

When I click on a cell it goes to the next screen but it keeps blank. Although my NSLog give s me the right url back.

Can anybody help ?

Kind regards.

**EDIT**

When I use http://www.google.be as url, it works.
But when I use this url: http://www.youtube.com/v/066PWBKrh6k&autoplay=1  it don't.

Comment: What does `setVideoURL` actually do? If it's a simple setter method and not triggering a `UIWebView` request load then that would be your root problem.

Comment: Thanky you for your answer. But check my edit please.

Comment: Wht happens when you put that URL in ur browser? It certainly does not lead me to a video in mobile safari.

Comment: I think the link is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem..

I tried your link which is 
http://www.youtube.com/v/066PWBKrh6k&autoplay=1 this link becomes to http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/066PWBKrh6k&autoplay=1  and it seems like this is not supported by iOS Safari ...

One possible Solution

use http://m.youtube.com/videoThatYouWant....

the safari should be able to display the video that you want...

Hope helps

Comment: Oké so the link is the problem.Thank you